# Why can't I search files and folders on my external NTFS drive on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, spotlight, external-disk, indexing, disk-volume

I have tried to re-index my external drive by removing it from Spotlight's privacy settings and putting it back there. I tried with mdutil in the terminal and I've got the following log:

```
bb:~ bb$ mdutil -i on -d /Volumes/TOSHIBA\ EXT
/Volumes/TOSHIBA EXT:
    Indexing and searching disabled.
bb:~ bb$ mdutil -i on /Volumes/TOSHIBA\ EXT
/Volumes/TOSHIBA EXT:
    Indexing enabled. 
bb:~ bb$
```

I tried it with the root password and when I look for files on my external drive I still cannot find them through spotlight even though I know they are on the drive and I can find them by browsing folders.

Is there another way to index my drive?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the drive to the privacy pane in System Preferences>Spotlight and them removing it from there (as explained in http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10330114-263.html)? Are you using Apple's NTFS driver (which only allows for read-only mounting) or something like NTFS-3G or Tuxera?

Comment: I tried it more than once.

Comment: What about the NTFS driver? Are you using Apple's, Tuxera's, or a driver from another vendor?

Comment: I have another driver I had installed back then when I had Leopard.

Comment: And, using your driver, can you write to the external NTFS drive or only read?

Comment: write and read. I just cannot search.

Comment: I had another ntfs drive before and I was able to search files on it, read and write. With this new drive I can only read and write I cannot search files.

Comment: Same problem here (Mountain Lion, new NTFS drive, WD Elements 2TB). No search. And as I can see, no answer to this question.